# Why some jQuery and JavaScript methods behave like that

Tags: javascript, jquery

I had to fire an event that checked for width of the screen to re adapt some specific arrows on a carousel because CSS breakpoint was not working.

I noticed that `$(window).width();` was not returning a correct width but it was always offset in some way making the arrows do weird things, and that these events were only called at the start and not called every time I resized:

`$(window).on('resize', function(){});`

`window.onresize = reportWindowSize;`

The ways I fixed both problems were using these methods:

- for the resize event:

  ```
  $(function() {
    $(window).resize(fixArrowMargin).trigger('resize');
  });
  ```
- for the browser's width:

  `window.innerWidth;`

Could someone provide me with an answer on how these methods work and why they behaved like that?

Edit: As requested:
Steps to reproduce problem i was having (arrows going over image which they should not)

Using Swiper element Library!

Please do note that i was creating a centered type carousel with 3 images one front, 1 left, 1 right

Html

```
<div class="carousel-box">
  <swiper-container class="carouselCws">
    <swiper-slide class="whole-slide">
       <div class="slider-image">IMG</div>
       <div class="text-container">h3 P</div>
       <div class="button">Learn More!</div>
    </swiper-slide>
  </swiper-container>
 <div class=arrows-to-slider>
    <img class="carouselCws-button-prev buttonS" src="imageUrl"></img>
    <img class="carouselCws-button-next buttonS" src="imageUrl"></img>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS, Only Pasted Css related to arrows and it's containers

```
   .carouselCws {
      height: 100%;
    }
    
    .arrow-to-slider {
      position: relative;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
    }
        
    .ButtonS {
         position: absolute;
         top: 50%;
         left: 50%;
         transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
         z-index: 2;
    }
    
    .carouselCws-button-prev { left: 31%; }
    
    .carouselCws-button-next { left: 69%; }
```

Comment: _"was always offset in some way"_ - What way? As far as I can see in the jQuery docs, that should _not_ be the case, as `window` as a source object will always return the `viewport width`. Perhaps good to start switching away from jQuery and into standard JS, so you can use `window.addEventListener( 'resize', resizeFunction )` and objects like `ResizeObserver`, while consistently just asking for `window.innerWidth`, which _has_ to be correct.

Comment: @somethinghere for example i have a 1920 width screen and in full screen the JQuery method returned 1909 which was not correct, as for ResizeOberserver i will have to document myself about it, i'm pretty new to web development, also thanks for the information about the javascript event listener

Comment: Is this perhaps because of scroll bars? That amount sounds potentially like scroll bars, as they tend to take space that you are supposed to have. How does your `fixArrowMargin` work? What are you doing? Because I think the issue might be that you are using fixed pixel sizes that include the scrollbar, while you might be better of with scalable CSS that places the things in the right space to begin with so you don't have to worry about it?

Comment: @somethinghere I just check for the 3 standard widths: phone, tablet and desktop and change margins using percentage because before this they were going over the image (they are outside of it) and they really should not (for the design i was going for)

Comment: Could you perhaps turn this into a minimal, reproducible snippet? With some HTML, the CSS you are using etc...? Because if your CSS and HTML is set up correctly,. you should not have to adjust anything like that with your JS. There are many solutions to achieve design, and JS is not the best one - once you use JS for design, it feels like you are trying to hack something together that can be solved more elegantly.

Comment: @somethinghere Updated Post because i did not know how to make it fit in a comment and did not know if it was apropriate, i hope that i did not miss anything

Comment: Thank you, it's a start, but I can't reproduce it with what you gave me. Is the goal to just layer the arrow box on top of the slider so they can control it? Because if that is the case, your wrapper should have position: relative, your arrow wrapper should be `width: 100%; position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 0; transform: translateY(-50%);` and your arrows should be `position: static`. Then your flexbox will space them correctly.

Comment: @somethinghere Does not even move lol- btw i actually tried in the past to add like a display flex to the swiper container well.. the carousel bugs out and disappears into oblivion slowly, btw it's my first carousel

Comment: Leave the swiper alone, just add another layer on top and use a wrapper around both to align them or something.